# Our migrate list in the close panel is essentially empty - What should we put in it?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

Occasionally a question can be migrated outright instead of closed as off topic; but only if we actually have some choices in the migrate list.

If I recall recorrectly there is a limit of how many migrates or migrate options are permitted but I'm thinking we can at least have some.

So, what common stack exchanges should we have in the close-migrate list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past 90 days, there have been 5 migrations:

- Academia
- Christianity (rejected)
- Earth Sciences (rejected)
- GIS
- Meta.History

All time, there have been 34 migrations away from History in its 1,115 days in beta.  That's just not enough to show a need for a default migration path even if they were all to one or two sites.

Comment: Ok. So do we use the flag or the like for migration requests? It just saddens me to see questions closed that might merit attention on a more topical site.

Comment: Yes. Moderators can migrate if need be. Just remember to [Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Comment: Would a migration path be an option even if there was a considerable volume of migrations? I was under the impression beta sites don't get migration paths (something about beta sites not being a permanent fixture on the network).

Comment: @YannisRizos: We have, I think, one migration path from a beta site.[citation needed] It's not so much that we never give beta sites migration paths as the bar is a bit higher for beta sites since migrations can be disruptive.

Answer (score 4):

Given that we now have a History of Science and Math SE, it might make sense to put that in the migration path, if and when both sites have matured enough. Unlike other sites such as Politics.SE, both History.SE and HSM.SE are about history.

Comment: As Yannis mentioned in a comment, we probably can't do that while either of the two sites is in beta. Still, it is something our posters here should be aware of as an option.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, I did specify "have matured".

Comment: Oh, that's what "matured" meant? Sorry. I'm nearing 50, and have given up waiting to for myself to start acting mature. So I guess my brain saw that phrase, said "Ha! As if!" and moved on. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The ones I seem to see requests for the most are politics and skeptics. I'm not sure the denizens of skeptics are big fans of getting other stack's trash all the time, so that one may be out. However, I get the impression Politics would actually like to take a lot of our misdirected political questions.

In fact, as I look over our flags, of the 16 outstanding, 6 of them (a whopping 38%) are requests to migrate various questions to the Politics stack.

I can't speak for the other mods, but migration requests are more challenging for me to handle than other mod actions, because the process generally involves hanging out in a chatroom, which is forbidden to me during work hours. So a migration path to that one stack that users could perform on their own initiative would help me a lot.

I think we have a Politics.SE mod or two who hang here, so hopefully they will pipe in.

Comment: Unfortunately, beta sites do not get migration paths (either in or out). There are a couple of exceptions, but I think it's safe to say that we'll have to wait until both sites graduate to set up a path to Politics. That said, you shouldn't feel you have to check up with us in Teacher's Lounge before migrating a question to Politics. If it's a good question, just go for it. We can always reject the migration if it happens to be off topic for us.

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons we do not have migrations is because there are no migration choices. Obviously we should have migration paths to religion.stackexchange.com, economics.stackexchange.com and a few others.